# How to make font become bold on blogger?

Tags: html, templates, fonts, blogs

I would like to ask about a problem on my blog. I hope someone can help me with it.
So I just use third-party templates for my blog page on blogger. Suddenly there's a problem when I use bold font. In the draft, when I click "bold", it still working. But when I published it, the font doesn't want to be bold. 
How to fix it?? Anybody knows?? Maybe by changing the codes? By I don't understand about code, at all.

Comment: It depends on the template. Did you try with different browsers? It is easier to help if we could look at the blog. However I'm not sure if this is on-topic or not on stackoverflow.

Comment: This sounds like a question you should be asking the third party template maker before asking here...?

Comment: Sorry if I asked place at the wrong place. I was asking at the blogger forum before, and one of the told me to ask at Stack Over Flow. But I'll try to ask with the third party template first know. Thanks